# How to resolve AcmeTestBundle:SomeClass to real path or class

Tags: php, symfony

How to properly resolve Symfony class name notation eg:

`AcmeTestBundle:Document`

to real path or class, like in this example to:

`Acme/TestBundle/Repository/Document`

I know that there are templating.name_parser and templating.locator services, but what about *custom* class names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Kernel#getBundle($name)`, you can get the bundle class instance. This bundle class has a `Bundle::getNamespace()` method to resolve the namespace part.

Then add your custom convention, like `/Repository/` and then the part after the colon:

```
$str = 'AcmeTestBundle:Document';
list($bundle, $class) = explode(':', $str, 2);

$baseNs = $kernel->getBundle($bundle)->getNamespace();
$fqcn = $baseNs.'\Repository\\'.$class; // Acme\TestBundle\Repository\Document
```